# Determine all prime numbers a,b,c for which the expression $a^2+b^2+c^2-1$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine all prime numbers a,b,c for which the expression $a^2+b^2+c^2-1$ is a perfect square

My approach : we know that $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2 +2ab+2bc+2ca$

$\Rightarrow $ the given equation to be a perfect square means $2ab+2bc+2ca =-1$

Is this approach correct, please guide how to take it further.. will be of great help thanks.

Comment: Your approach seems completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: The square needs not be the square of $a+b+c$. For example $2^2+2^2+3^2 - 1 = 4^2$ but $2+2+3 \ne 4$.

Comment: What should be the approach then.. please guide thanks

Comment: Take into account that all primes larger than $3$ are of the form $6k\pm1$. This helps you exclude the cases where all $a,b,c$ are larger than $3$. Since otherwise $a^2+b^2+c^2-1$ will have remainder $1+1+1-1=2$ modulo $6$. But perfect squares  leave remainders $0,1,3,4$ modulo $6$. So, some of $a,b,c$ must be $2$ or $3$. Assume that $a=2$ and $b,c>3$. Then $a^2+b^2+c^2-1$ gives remainder $5$ modulo $6$. Cannot be. Now analyze the case of $a=2,b=3$ and the case $a=3$ and $b,c>3$.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo $4$ all squares are $0$ or $1$. If all of $a,b,c$ are odd primes (not $2$) we have $a^2+b^2+c^2-1\equiv2\bmod4$, which is a contradiction. For similar reasons we cannot have all three of $a,b,c$ being $2$, so there must be one or two $2$'s (which we will assign by default to the earliest variables in alphabetical order). If two, we have $7+c^2=d^2$ with the only solution being $c=3$ (and $d=4$).

It remains to check the one-$2$ case. plop's comment rules out the $b,c>3$ case, so we are left with $a=2$, $b=3$ and the equation $12+c^2=d^2$, whose only solution is $c=2$ – but this is the same as the previous considered case up to variable reordering.

Hence the only solutions to $a^2+b^2+c^2-1=d^2$ with $a,b,c$ primes are $\{a,b,c\}=\{2,2,3\}$.